# What is the Stochastic Differential Equation associated with $X_t = \frac{1}{t+W_t}$ where $W_t$ is a Wiener Process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

What is the Stochastic Differential Equation associated with $X_t = \frac{1}{t+W_t}$ where $W_t$ is a Wiener Process? I have tried to apply Ito's Formula here, but there is a discontinuity at $0$. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Thinking that $W_t$ returns to $0$ infinitely many times near $t = 0$ and $W_t$ grows like $\sqrt{t}$, I am worried that zeros of $t+W_t$ may accumulate near $0$. Do you really want that our Wiener process begins at $0$?

Comment: @SangchulLee: Indeed by the Cameron-Martin theorem the zeros do accumulate near 0.

Comment: @SangchulLee Hi, yes I was given this problem for a class I taught.

Comment: So is this problem undefined?

Comment: I would go back to whoever posed this problem and ask them just what they think is going on near $t=0$.